# Black lines on render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

When I render images it always shows some black thick lines like on the bottom and top. How to remove it?

[image]

Comment: could you upload your blendfile?

Comment: You will have to upload a blend file. I have never seen anything like that before. Check to make sure you don't have any objects hidden from view that might be obstructing the camera during render.

Comment: Your problem is most likely a rendering glitch, is you have nothing blocking it, which is unlikely. It might be something like messed up files. When did it start happening? When did you install Blender? If you just installed it, then I would re-install.

Comment: i am having the same problem please respond if you found an answer

Comment: @anthony seems like the original question was abandoned and left unresolved, probably for lack of information. Please make a new post using the "ask a question" link http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/ask please include as much information as you can and if possible include a link to your file. Maybe this time we'l be able to find a solution...